# Flexbox column having translated items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating a div of 11 items, devided by 2 columns.
So the result is that the fist row of 2 elements are correctly positioned,
the last item is correctly positioned. But the items inbetween are moved to the left.
I'm using flexbox for a long time but I can't see any problems with my code.

[image]

my html code:

```
<div class="postview">

<?php while ($_posts->have_posts()): $_posts->the_post();?>

<h1><a class="post-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></h1>
   <div class="posts-layout">
       <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
       <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('post-picture'); ?>" alt="">
   </div>  
 </a>  
</div>
```

```
.postview {
    width: 65vw;
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: initial;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: 8vh;
    margin-bottom: 4vh;
}

.post-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.posts-layout {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(206, 45, 45);
    width: 30vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.posts-layout h1 {
    font-size: 2vh;
    color: black;
}
``
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: @Stef_Verniers plz add your html code...

Comment: check edits please

Comment: I did added html

Comment: If you want us to help you, change attached HTML so it will be without php and with some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the answer.

Your problem is not the flexbox. Your problem is HTML nesting.
You're not supposed to do things like this:

```
<h1><a href="|"></h1> ... </a>
```

This is the root of your problem.

You supposed to have something like this:

```
<div class="posts-layout">
  <a class="post-link" href="|">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="random image">
  </a>  
</div>
```

**Second**, read this:
[Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

That will lead to a far better experience on StackOverflow than you have now.

**Third**, if you don't know how to add random images to your code, get yourself familiar with https://picsum.photos/.

**Fourth**, please use the VScode or something like that. It will most likely highlight all these kinds of blinders.

PS No hard feelings, all of that is just a very trivial thing. I hope you'll have time to read this before your question gets deleted.

**PPS** Also, https://www.grammarly.com/ will be useful to you.